# Using a Button as "checkbox" in form_for?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

At the moment I'm building a small project for myself and came up with an idea.

Can you use a button as toggle in a form_for to set a bool in the DB?
I want to have a green button if the bool is true and a red one if the bool is false.

If I click the button, it should change his color and value and if I submit the form, it should pass that value to the create method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a normal checkbox, and research “custom checkboxes” to see what techniques are available to get them display as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this 
[Orginal link from where code is taken](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think a custom checkbox is the better choice here, but, if you really want to use a button, I would use a hidden checkbox field and apply onclick functions to the button to change the value of a hidden checkbox field.
Here is a pen with the general idea http://codepen.io/kaykayyali/pen/WpwvyE

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' id='hidden_check_box'>
<button class='red' id='toggle_button' onclick="toggle_checkbox()">
```

CSS

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

JS

```
function toggle_checkbox() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('hidden_check_box');
  var button = document.getElementById('toggle_button');
  if (!checkbox.checked) {
    checkbox.checked = true;
    button.className = 'green';
  }
  else {
    checkbox.checked = false;
    button.className = 'red';
  }
  console.log(checkbox.checked);
}
```